# MSSQL delete using row constructors

Tags: mysql, sql-server, constructor, row

in MySQL, I use this query to delete some rows:

```
DELETE 
   FROM test 
   WHERE (id1, id2) IN ((1, 1), (2,1), (3,1))
```

*composite PK(id1,id2)

this query wont works on MsSQL. Anyone can tell me the equivalent query on MsSQL

Comment: Whats your 'id's datatype?  If its varchar this should work.: 
`delete from test  where (id1, id2) in (('1', '1'), ('2', '1'), ('3', '1'))`

Comment: @Kayathiri not on SQL Server.

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you out, refer to this please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

This should work, it is a bit more verbose though:

```
DELETE
FROM test 
WHERE id1 IN (1, 2 , 3) AND id2 = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Though there may be a better approach to solving your problem, if you really want to use a row constructor, you can simply join to a virtual entity that is created using a value constructor. Here is an example:

**Creating some test data**

```
create table test (
    id1 int not null,
    id2 int not null,
    primary key clustered (id1, id2));

insert test (
    id1,
    id2)
select top (100)
    id1,
    id2
from (
    select distinct
        id1 = abs(checksum(newid())) % 10,
        id2 = abs(checksum(newid())) % 10
    from sys.columns a
    cross join sys.columns b) c;
```

**Deleting rows using a row constructor**

```
delete a
from test a
join (
    values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)) b(id1, id2)
        on a.id1 = b.id1
            and a.id2 = b.id2;
```

The above DML query should result in deleting three rows from `test`.